# ¿Por qué tenemos la etiqueta "distinción-vs-seseo" pero no "seseo"?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas

He observado que tenemos una etiqueta [ceceo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceceo), y una etiqueta [distinción-vs-seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinci%c3%b3n-vs-seseo), pero ninguna etiqueta [seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seseo). Tampoco entiendo qué quiere decir el nombre de la etiqueta [distinción-vs-seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinci%c3%b3n-vs-seseo): no se me ocurre ninguna manera en que la "distinción" y el "seseo" puedan estar contrapuestos justificando el uso de la "preposición" "vs". ¿Hay alguna razón histórica que no he encontrado en mi búsqueda en Meta, o deberíamos reemplazar [distinción-vs-seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinci%c3%b3n-vs-seseo) por [seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seseo)?

Comment: Se introdujo [hace un par de años](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/revisions/3477/4) por un moderador de [english.se], donde estas etiquetas [XX-vs-YY] son muy comunes. Estoy contigo en que no hay contraposición posible y que [tag:seseo] a secas ya cumpliría la función, pero lo mismo sería bueno hablarlo con tchrist para que nos explique su lógica al respecto.

Comment: La etiqueta [tag:ceceo] tiene 3 preguntas, y [tag:distinción-vs-seseo] tiene 8. Tal vez sea una buena idea unificar todas estas preguntas bajo una única etiqueta "ceceo-seseo", o incluso "ceceo-seseo-distinción", aunque esta ya me hace un poco larga, entiendo que cuando se habla de distinción es en contraposición al ceceo o al seseo, por lo que el concepto de distinción iría implícito en "ceceo-seseo" (según mi rebatible opinión).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por dejarlo expresado en una respuesta, voy a proceder a unificar todas las preguntas bajo las etiquetas [ceceo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceceo) y [distinción-vs-seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distinci%c3%b3n-vs-seseo) (que juntas suman 11 a día de hoy) bajo una etiqueta nueva [ceceo-seseo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceceo-seseo), que entiendo que será mucho más útil para el sitio al eliminar la excesiva fragmentación que ocasiona el tener demasiadas etiquetas con tan pocas preguntas cada una.

Comment: Bien hecho. Podrías crear el sinónimo también de [tag:ceceo] y [tag:seseo] para que apunten a la nueva y así ayudar a quien intente usarla.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' hecho.